# Stored procedure (insert data into a table and then insert the generated id into another) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert data into table 1, then I want to insert the generated idAddress into table 2, how can I do this?

Table 1 
PK-idAddress,
street,
cp

Table 2
PK-idUser,
FK-idAddress,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
INSERT INTO table1(STREET, CP) VALUES('THIS', 'THAT')
INSERT INTO table2(FK-IDADDRESS) VALUES(@@IDENTITY) -- OR SCOPE_IDENTITY
```

Well, since I'm not sure of your tables structure and of your full code, that's just an assumption up there (my code, I mean) -- Basically, it's calling `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY` -- read into the links below to get an idea of what you might really need.

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

[@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

[DIFFERENCE BETWEEN...](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_IDENTITY.aspx)

There's another method you can use:

[IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

And you can read this too:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Functions_-_@@IDENTITY,_SCOPE_IDENTITY,_IDENT_CURRENT

***credit goes to @JakeFeasel for bringing up `IDENT_CURRENT`**

Comment: I prefer ident_current('table1') - sometimes, insert triggers are running in the background that may be doing other inserts, and can thus throw @@identity off.

Comment: Yeah, when I realized that I wasn't sure of the full SQL code, I modified my answer and provided info on both `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `@@IDENTITY`...but let me modify it one more time to include the root of your comment.. Thanks!